# How do I create a Pipfile from an existing virtualenv?

Tags: pip, virtualenv, pipenv

I can't seem to find the exact answer here. Is it possible to work without requirements.txt at all?

With pip (or pipenv), if I have a virtual environment, I can generate requirements.txt easily.

But, what if I have a project where we're trying to move to using pipfiles entirely. How do I initialize the pipfile from the existing virtualenv? In such a way that I can get rid of requirements.txt

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

1. rm Pipfile
2. rm Pipfile.lock
3. source path/to/venv/bin/activate
4. pip freeze > requirements.txt
5. pipenv install -r requirements.txt
6. rm requirements.txt
7. Rule the world

-- In english:

1. Delete or rename Pipfile and Pipefile.lock
2. Activate the virtual env
3. Use pip freeze to create a requirements.txt file
4. Use pipenv to install from the requirement.txt file. This initializes the Pipefile as well
5. Delete the requirements.txt file
6. Grab a coffee

The generated Pipfile will be version locked, but easy to edit.

Comment: $ pipenv install -r requirements.txt 

Usage: pipenv install [OPTIONS] [PACKAGES]...

ERROR:: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile installation, not installation of specific packages. Aborting.

Comment: You did something wrong, @EricVB - It's `pipenv install -r requirements.txt`, the command...

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @luke throws an error because `pipenv` needs the `Pipfile` to locate the corresponding environment within the `.virtualenvs` (user) folder.

The following works for me (from BASH):

```
pipenv run pip freeze > requirements.txt
pipenv install -r requirements.txt
rm requirements.txt
```

from CMD:

```
pipenv run pip freeze > requirements.txt
pipenv install -r requirements.txt
del requirements.txt
```

there is no need to remove the old `Pipfile` or `Pipfile.lock` files. `pipenv` will overwrite them.